# Using software/website, guess the limit

Tags: limits

It is asked to guess the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{3-h}^{3+h} x^2 \, \Bbb dx$$ using website or software.

I have shown that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{3-h}^{3+h} x^2 \, \Bbb dx = 9$$ just integrating and using L’Hospital’s rule. But I don’t understand what does it mean using software or website.

Comment: Actually, the result should be zero because we integrate over an arbitrarily short interval with a continuous function. This is easily shown by computation, but as it seems from the problem statement, today's kids should rather google the result than think for themselves ... (Btw, your result is for $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac 1{2h}\int_{3-h}^{3+h}x^2\,\mathrm dx$)

Comment: But sir what does it mean ** using software or website ? **

Comment: It means that you should stop using pen and paper and brain, and instead use some software or web service to arrive at the result ...

Comment: A common approach is to use software that uses symbolic computation, such as MatLab symbolic toolbox, _Mathematica_, etc.  If I were to proceed with this question, I would symbolically integrate the integral and then take the limit, using _built-in functions_ inside those softwares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this refers to something like http://www.wolframalpha.com
You can enter your math problem there and it will try to find a solution for it. Usually however without an explicit proof—you can see step-by-step solutions only if you sign up as “Pro subscriber”. Maybe that’s why it says “guess”. You can also use the software Mathematica to do similar stuff.